# Using sed to replace javascript code in multiple files

Tags: bash, sed, awk

I need to replace an old google analytics code with the new universal tracking code in lots of static html files.
The old code looks like this:

```
_uacct = "UA-XXXXXX-X";
urchinTracker();
```

The new code is the following:

```
(function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){(i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)})(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');ga('create', 'UA-XXXXXX-X', 'xxx.com');ga('require', 'displayfeatures');ga('send', 'pageview');
```

I'm trying to combine bash find command and sed (CentOS 6):

```
find docs/ -type f -iname "*.html" -exec sed -i ':a;N;$!ba;s/_uacct = "UA-XXXXXX-X";\nurchinTracker();/(function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i[\'GoogleAnalyticsObject\']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){(i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)})(window,document,\'script\',\'\/\/www.google-analytics.com\/analytics.js\',\'ga\');ga(\'create\', \'UA-XXXXXX-X\', \'xxx.com\');ga(\'require\', \'displayfeatures\');ga(\'send\', \'pageview\');/g' {} \;
```

However, this produces the following error:

```
-bash: syntax error near unexpected token `('
```

After some research I found the brackets should be escaped as well:

```
find arts/ -type f -iname "bass.html" -exec sed -i ':a;N;$!ba;s/_uacct = "UA-XXXXXX-X";\nurchinTracker();/\(function\(i,s,o,g,r,a,m\){i[\'GoogleAnalyticsObject\']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function\(\){\(i[r].q=i[r].q||[]\).push\(arguments\)},i[r].l=1*new Date\(\);a=s.createElement\(o\),m=s.getElementsByTagName\(o\)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore\(a,m\)}\)\(window,document,\'script\',\'\/\/www.google-analytics.com\/analytics.js\',\'ga\'\);ga\(\'create\', \'UA-XXXXXX-X\', \'xxx.com\'\);ga\(\'require\', \'displayfeatures\'\);ga\(\'send\', \'pageview\'\);/g' {} \;
> 
>
```

As you may see bash thinks something is not escaped, breaks the line and
does not execute the command.

What I'm doing wrong?

If this is possible to do with another tool (let's say awk)?

Comment: This very similar question produced a satisfactory answer in `awk`: http://www.unix.com/shell-programming-and-scripting/137367-replace-block-text-content-another-file.html

Comment: I'd suggest a proper script in perl or python though.. You're going to be stretching `sed` with multi-line replace

Answer (score 1):

You [can't escape single quotes inside single quotes](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Single-Quotes.html#Single-Quotes). The easiest way for you is to put your script in a file and then run

```
find arts/ -type f -iname "bass.html" -exec sed -i -f your-script.sed '{}' \;
```

Answer (score 0):

That worked for me

```
find docs/ -type f -iname "*.html" -exec \
perl -i.bak -0pe 's/_uacct = "UA-XXXXXX-X";\nurchinTracker\(\);/test/igs' {} \;
```

Notice that `-i.bak` makes a copy of the original file with extension `.bak`, in case anything goes wrong. The replacement is now the string `test`. Replace that with your long replacement.

With your huge replacement it would then look like:

```
find docs/ -type f -iname "*.html" -exec perl -i.bak -0pe "s/_uacct = \"UA-XXXXXX-X\";\nurchinTracker\(\);/\(function\(i,s,o,g,r,a,m\)\{i\['GoogleAnalyticsObject'\]=r;i\[r\]=i\[r\]\|\|function\(\)\{\(i\[r\].q=i\[r\].q\|\|\[\]\).push\(arguments\)\},i\[r\].l=1\*new Date\(\);a=s.createElement\(o\),m=s.getElementsByTagName\(o\)\[0\];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore\(a,m\)\}\)\(window,document,'script','\/\/www.google-analytics.com\/analytics.js','ga'\);ga\('create', 'UA-XXXXXX-X', 'xxx.com'\);ga\('require', 'displayfeatures'\);ga\('send', 'pageview'\);/igs" {} \;
```